# save dynamic page for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing a simple website and I am new to web programming. The initial page is dynamically generated using javascript. When user clicks on a link, and then comes back using browsers back button, the page is reloaded every time. I am unable to find out how to stop page from reloading and cache it in browser's history. I have tried pagecreate and pageinit event from jquery mobile, but of no help. They are called every time on back button. Please help me, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This is not how browsers work. If you navigate to a new page, the page is reloaded, some or all of that data may be in the cache, but the browser still performs a reload. You can use ajax to change contents of a page without reloading. You can also use hashes so that back/forward still work.

Comment: How to use ajax to change contents without reloading? That is exactly I want to know. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: Here is a simple example. http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the HTML 5 [History API](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#history-api).

```
link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // manually add a value to the history stack
  // without making the browser load any new page
  history.pushState('Contact Page Form', 'Contact Page', '/contact');
});

// capture navigation in case we want to change,
// for instance, some content when it changes
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = event.state; // 'Contact Page Form'
});
```